# Using JNDI with Jetty 8

Tags: jetty, jndi, embedded-jetty

I am trying to configure Jetty 8 (to be specific: 8.1.4.v20120524) to use JNDI. In my jetty.xml file I have the following configuration:

```
<Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
</Array>

<Call name="setAttribute">
  <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.configuration</Arg>
  <Arg>
      <Ref id="plusConfig"/>
  </Arg>
</Call>

<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
  <Arg>stopport</Arg>
  <Arg type="java.lang.Integer">8888</Arg>
  <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg>
</New>
```

I am calling this from Java using embedded jetty:

```
      Server jetty = (Server) new XmlConfiguration(<myconfig>).configure();
      jetty.start();
      InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
      Integer sport = (Integer) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/stopport");
```

However, the JNDI binding seems to be incomplete/incorrect as this fails with:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/stopport'
org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:500)
org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:531)
org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:546)
org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:112)
javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
org.basex.BaseXHTTP.<init>(BaseXHTTP.java:80)
org.basex.BaseXHTTP.main(BaseXHTTP.java:47)
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/stopport'
```

The actual code can be found at https://github.com/dirkk/basex-api/tree/basexjetty in src/main/resources/.basexjetty (this is the jetty.xml, just renamed) and src/main/java/org/basex/BaseXHTTP.java

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: when you say 'calling this from Java' where is that java code located, inside of a webapp or some other scope?

Comment: I edited the Java snippet to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the wrong constructor on EnvEntry is getting used when wiring this up

try this and let me know if that works:

```
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
  <Arg></Arg>
  <Arg>stopport</Arg>
  <Arg type="java.lang.Integer">8888</Arg>
  <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg>
</New>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not :(

Comment: this is tagged as embedded-jetty, are processing the jetty.xml file directly using XMLConfiguration or something? something seems off

Comment: you know, based on your added bit of java, this should work since you need to set it to jvm level scope...perhaps this is an issue in the jvm scoping, though every time I think that and go look jetty has been right, I would try and access that inside webapp or handler or to just see if it is a scoping issue

Comment: "should work" is what I am thinking since today morning... ;)
I editet the question again, please see the last paragraph with the link to my github repo. It is an open-source project, so actually there is no reason why I should withhold that. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!